# Does cascade delete work through all associations or just the immediate one?

Tags: hibernate, jpa

In my project modal I have a chain of 3 @OneToMany mappings combining 4 classes.  If I only set the top level mapping to cascade delete will the delete cascade through all 4 classes or do I have to specifically set all of the mappings to cascade as well?

Similarly, if I grab the top level data using a left join fetch to get the second level data will I also receive the other 2 mapped classes as well or do I need to write a triple join fetch?

I am using Hibernate with JPA annotations.

Answer (score 0):

You can configure Cascade/Fetch behavior in annotation. For example:

```
@OneToMany(cascade={CascadeType.ALL}, fetch=FetchType.LAZY)
```

You should set cascade delete in all classes.
You do not need "triple join fetch", you will get the data with a single fetch.